# iOS upgrade won't transfer music from iPhone 4 onto Mac

Tags: mac

Some works, the rest is gray/locked. I tried Manual sync, but that isn't working, and keeps messing up. Now I can't even sync at all. The `Apply` button in gone on iTunes so is sync. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking on your device in iTunes and clicking "transfer purchases"?

Usually it transfers stuff from the device to iTunes, but in this case it should do the opposite.

Comment: Yeah, that's *not* how we're spamming with `softwarebbs.com` again.